# Can't validate AWS EB SSL cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I changed the DNS records on my godaddy domain to point to my Elastic Beanstalk url, and the redirect works fine.

But when I request a cert from AWS, it e-mails `admin@mydomain.com` (mx record says `10 inbound-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`) but I have no idea how to access that mailbox. Tried SES, Workmail, and GoDaddy says they can't help because the records are with AWS now.

`Letsencrypt/certbot` says

> the requested url was not found

when I ssh into EB. Any ideas on how to obtain a certificate would save my life.

Comment: That MX record indicates you have SES inbound email setup for your domain. If you have no idea how to access emails for your domain then who set that up? If SES is actually configured to handle inbound emails for your domain then it is probably delivering them to an S3 bucket. I suggest reading up on how SES inbound email handling works and verify that you can receive emails for your domain before requesting an SSL certificate.

Comment: ACM also sends email to the contact addresses for the domain, which you can update with your registrar. You only have to receive one of them, to get the link that you need.  If you aren't receiving mail addressed to the domain contacts, you need to fix that, as well.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if you request a `www` or `*` certificate the ACM service doesn't look up your registrar contact details. It sends emails to admin@, administrator@, hostmaster@, postmaster@, and webmaster@ in that case.

Comment: @MarkB Yes! The emails were just dumping into an S3 bucket, which I could open and follow the link to verify ownership.